# Remote SSH Server, No Firewall NAT Allowed, Teamviewer Like Solutions?

Tags: remote-access

I have a server (Linux,SSH) sitting inside of a remote company. It is installed on a secured / isolated part of their network but has internet access. We need to manage it, but can not get a firewall port forward into the system.

There seems to not be a lot of literature / solutions for headless Linux systems (I do see Teamviewer can sometimes do it with a fake VGA adapter). Ideally native SSH support would be preferred, over a windowed Teamviewer like client, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Does anyone have solutions to a access issue like this?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. You can try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: why not use ssh as a jump host? or setup guacamole